# 50 leds in series

Tags: led, 12v

Creating beer pong table and would like to wire 51 LEDs per side.  Can I simply connect in series 3 LEDs at a time with resistor required? I've already done the math for each of the 3 sets of LEDs but is there a max number of LEDs I can put together.  I want to be able to plug this into the wall vs battery power as I already have an infinity mirror in the middle that need plugged in but I will not be connecting the two together.  Very new to this and I want to be safe and not burn LEDs or burn down the house.

Thanks

Comment: If you're feeling uncertain about this they sell prefab LED strips designed to run off 12V at various retailers.

Comment: You won't be able to "plug this into the wall" directly. If you're planning on 12V power, make sure you also have a reasonable power supply for this application.

Answer (score 2):

Your tag says 12 V so I guess you are planning a layout as shown in Figure 1. Most of the LED strips are laid out like this in a repeating pattern of three LEDs and their current-limiting resistors along a flexible circuit. There will be scissors marks every 10 cm or so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqi2tv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Cut along the dotted line.*

You could use these or make your own in a similar fashion. The strips use two resistors to share the power dissipation.

- Figure out what the forward voltage drop is for each LED at the current you intend to run it. e.g., 2.2 V at 20 mA.
- The voltage across the series resistor will be 12 - 3 x 2.2 = 12 - 6.6 = 5.4 V.
- R will be given by \$ R = \frac {V_R}{I} = \frac {5.4}{0.02} = 270~\Omega \$.
- The power dissipated in the resistor will be \$ P = VI = 5.4 \times 0.02 = 0.11~W\$.
- Total current will be \$ 17~strings \times 20~mA = 340~mA \$. Your power supply needs to be this rating.
- Total power will be \$ P = VI = 12~V \times 340~mA = 4980~mW = 5~W \$.

A single 270 Ω, 1/4 watt resistor in each string of three LEDs will be fine (for the assumed LEDs).

Comment: Similar I was hoping that I would be able to just use one resistor on the positive side of each set of three LEDs or is one required I between each led, but that was very close to what I was thinking.

Comment: They're laid out as shown in the strips to avoid the cut line. You need one resistor per three-LED string and it can be in any position: +, middle or - end of the string.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much for your help.  I think I have it now.  Thanks for the clarification.  Is this called series than vs parallel?  Based on the voltage drop I think all of the "sets" if that's what they are called will start with a resistor 3 LEDs then to ground repeat 17 times.

Comment: You've got it. You are creating 17 parallel connected sets of three series connected LEDs with current limiting resistor in each set. If you're happy with the answer you can accept it or wait a day or two to see if any better answers come in. Sometimes someone will have another angle which may be of interest. I've added a few more calculations.

Comment: It's both series (S) and parallel (P) when using a switched array 3S17P .  The 5m Stripleds come in different colours and are designed to run with variable brightness from 10 to 14.2V for car use or just a PC power supply using 12V. If you intended to only use 12V and DIY, then other design variations are possible.

Comment: Why are "R1" and "R2" separate resistors? Why not just one (sum of two values)?

Comment: You'd need to ask the manufacturers. Ideas I can think of include: they can be combined but will dissipate twice the power. This way spreads the heat. "We only use this size of resistor". (Unlikely.)  Two of these are cheaper than one of those. (Maybe.) The smaller package doesn't stress the joints as much when rolled up. (Good?)